# C# Generate unique secure random strings gradually

Tags: c#, random, unique

I want to generate unique and secure strings randomly and I want to do it over time. I want to choose the shortest possible length for my use (Big enough so that random tries fail with good chance). I Also want the process to be fast. Using the following code and testing it for uniqueness, duplicates occur sooner than I expected. I'm not sure if there is any problem.

P.S.: Is it secure to use a pool for generated numbers?

P.P.S: I prefer not to add '-' and '_' to the alphabet. Is it worth removing it?

```
string Alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_";
string Random(int length,string alphabet)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(uint)];
                rng.GetBytes(buffer);
                uint num = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);
                result.Append(alphabet[(int)(num % (uint)alphabet.Length)]);
            }
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Comment: Maybe it might help to run a spell check on your code. Looking at it, the code will not run at all.

Comment: @t0mm13b I was chrome spell check showing me I misspelled "length" and I changed it during the posting. code is correct. and I edited the post.

Comment: @Lucifer The answer in the mentioned post, said to use one instance of Random. but for my application it is not possible.

Comment: `duplicates occur sooner than I expected.` When did you expect them? When did they occur?

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: @mjwills after only less than 1% of all possible strings

Comment: You like to live a dangerous life. if `alphabet.Length` isn't a divisor of 256 you'll get some letters to be more common than others. To make a clear example: if `alphabet.Length == 129`, then the first 127 letters have two values that are corresponding (alphabet[0] == 0 and 129. alphabet[1] == 1 and 130 and so on), while the last two letters (alphabet[127] and alphabet[128]) have a single value each.

Comment: @mjwills I am going to include it in a RandomUtility class and use it for (file names, tokens for a custom protocol, custom unique ids)

Comment: "Short" and "secure" are two things that generally don't go well together. Anything that's sufficiently short can also be brute forced and/or predicted easily. What's more, you don't want things to be secure by having a name that's hard to guess, you want them to be secure by not being accessible at all. If you use 16 random bytes and convert them to a 32 character hexstring and be done with it, you'll have 128 bits worth of randomness. That's certainly good enough to prevent collisions. So is `Guid.NewGuid()` for that matter, though that's not cryptographically secure.

Comment: @JeroenMostert noted! I will change my strategies. And by making the strings longer I get enough unique strings. BUT... the question in the corner of my mind, why this function is generates duplicates so soon (`after only less than 1% of all possible strings generated` )?

Comment: Have you read xanatos' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem link @AliSh?

Answer (score 0):

In general, in your `Alphabet` each character has 6 bits of "information" (there are 64 characters). So a string of length = 10 has 60 bits of information. For the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) after sqrt(2^60), that is 2^30, you should have a 0.5 possibility (50%) of a collision. 2^30 is quite big, but if the number of characters is lower then the collision will happen much earlier.

Note that there is a possible optimization that can be done in your code (preallocating the "correct" length of StringBuilder) and there is a bug:

```
public const string BaseAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_";

public static string Random(int length, string alphabet = BaseAlphabet)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(length);
    uint maxValue = (uint)((((ulong)uint.MaxValue) + 1) / (uint)alphabet.Length * (uint)alphabet.Length);

    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            uint num;

            do
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(uint)];
                rng.GetBytes(buffer);
                num = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);
            }
            while (num >= maxValue);

            result.Append(alphabet[(int)(num % (uint)alphabet.Length)]);
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Some characters could be more probable than others in the code you wrote. This because if (`uint.MaxValue + 1`) (the whole range of possible numbers generated by the rng) isn't perfectly divisible by `alphabet.Length` then the characters at the end of `alphabet` are less probable than the characters at the beginning.